# Ruby on Rails testing connection to DB through irb , NameError Uninitialized Constant Article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I’m running into an issue where I want to test out the connection to the db. I’m trying to access my Articles table. I have a file in models “article.rb” and inside it has:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

end
```

When I go to my CMD and type the command “rails console” then follow up in IRB with “Article.all” I am receiving this error

```
2.7.1 :001 > Article.all
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Article)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is the file named in which you defined the `Article` class and where is the file located?

Comment: @spickermann article.rb located in a folder named models located in folder named app

Comment: @spickermann I added an extra picture to show the project directory

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the solution as advised from a user on /r/rails using the command bin/spring stop